# Creating a deck of playing cards using a LinkedList in java

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

im not sure what I'm doing here, but I'm trying to work with the LinkedList collection in java to create a deck of playing cards. there seems to be an error in my logic. i keep getting a NullPointerException in the deck constructor.

I am trying to rework code that used an array to use a LikedList instead. What am i missing?

```
public class Deck {

/** 
 * A LinkedList of cards in the deck, where the top card is the 
 * first index.
 */
private LinkedList<Card> mCards;

/**
 * Number of cards currently in the deck
 */
private int numCards;


/**No args Constructor- if no arguments are used when creating a deck,
 * then we define the game deck to be one deck without shuffling.
 * 
 */
public Deck(){ this(1, false); }

/**Constructor that defines the number of decks (how many sets of 52
 *              cards are in the deck) and whether it should be shuffled.
 * 
 * @param numDecks the number of individual decks in this game deck
 * @param isShuffled whether to shuffle the cards
 */
public Deck(int numDecks, boolean isShuffled){

    this.numCards = numDecks * 52;

    //for each deck
    for (int i = 0; i < numDecks; i++){

        //for each suit
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){

            //for each number
            for(int k = 1; k <= 13; k++){

                //add card to the deck
                this.mCards.add(new Card(Suit.values()[j], k));
            }
        }
    }
    if(isShuffled){
        this.shuffle();
}
```

---

```
public enum Suit {
   Clubs,
   Diamonds,
   Spades,
   Hearts,
}
```

Comment: You don't init `mCards`. Also, program to the interface. `List<...> mCards = new LinkedList<>()`.

Comment: If i change to List, what do i use instead of pop() to remove the first element?

Comment: Either `remove(0)` or use the `Queue` interface if that's how you are using the `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never initialize `mCards`.

Add (at the beginning of your constructor) :

```
mCards = new LinkedList<Card>();
```